# Pass Image as byte Stream through Ajax to Controller - Mvc4

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, asp.net-mvc-4

Can we pass a image as a binary stream to the controller?

```
<img src="something.png">
```

This needs to be passed to Controller using the byte stream.

How can I Implement this..?

Comment: Instead of using ajax you should read the file data server side.

Comment: @Musa, thanks for reply.. But the requirement is like as I mentioned. So I need a possible solution for that.

Comment: What you'd need to do is get the image data as a `blob` and upload that.

Comment: @Musa can give a brief explanation on this with a sample code?

Comment: @Musa, I have gone through the 'blob', it supports IE 10 and later versions. It doesn't support IE 9. I need it to support that also..

Comment: Well then you'll have to use a plugin like flash/java/silverlight

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get bytes of that image using the below line at client side

```
var myImage = document.getElementById('myimage');
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);

var mydataURL=myCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

pass `mydataURL` to controller from ajax as `string`.

**Example:**

```
<img id="myimage" src="something.png" />
<canvas width="300" height="300" id="mycanvas" style="display: none;"></canvas>
```

Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "YourAction/YourMethod",
   data:'{DataUrl:'+ mydataURL +'}',
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   datatype: "json",
   success:function(response){
    // alert(response.d); whatever you want to return as message.
   }
});
```

Controller Code

```
public string YourMethod(string DataUrl){
  // your logic
 return "Success!!!";
}
```